# Is there anything in physics that is absolute rather than relative?

Tags: reference-frames, relative-motion

Are there physical quantities that are absolute rather than relative? Things that do not depend on the reference frame? Perhaps I just haven’t learned about them yet.

Original (before edit by @G.Smith):

Is there anything as absolute and not relative or which has no concern with reference frame? Or I don't know anything yet?

Comment: In Special and General Relativity there is a fundamental upper cosmic speed limit i.e. the speed of light. The speed of a photon does not change with the change in reference frame and this is one of the foundations of relativity.

Comment: What if we could take another photon as reference point, as we can't till now?

Comment: Wouldn't it bring a change then?

Comment: sorry but it doesn't make sense. Have a read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_light

Comment: Must be your second sentence then...

Comment: I am assuming that the downvotes are due to the way that the question was expressed (probably due to the OP not being a native English speaker). I think it is a valid and interesting question, which is why I have answered it.  Am I allowed to improve the phrasing of the question?

Comment: I have edited the question on behalf f the OP to make it clear. I believe that I correctly understood what the OP was trying to ask. I request that it be reopened so that others can answer.

Answer (score 3):

Not everything is relative. There are lots of absolute quantities that do not depend on the reference frame in which they are measured. Here are a dozen examples, chosen because of their fundamental nature:

The speed of light.

The invariant mass of any elementary particle.

The electric charge of any elementary particle.

The spin of any elementary particle.

The difference between the squared magnitudes of the electric and magnetic fields at any point.

The expectation value of the Higgs field at any point.

The spacetime interval along a worldline between two events.

The Ricci curvature at a point in spacetime.

The Kretschmann invariant at a point in spacetime.

The Chern-Pontryagin invariant at a point in spacetime.

The Euler invariant at a point in spacetime.

The number of dimensions of spacetime.